# Apply normal or not-normal test to heterogeneously normal data sub-sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normality-assumption

I have a dataset made by measuring something on standard dilutions ranging from let's say 10, 100, 1000 and 10000. I checked how the results are distributed with the Shapiro-Wilk test, and it turns out something like this:

```
GROUP  P-VALUE
10     0.00475
100    0.07890
1000   0.04561
10000  0.03594
```

Since only one of the groups is normally distributed (100),  shall I use non-parametric test for all groups? [and parametric in the reverse case, I presume]. Or shall I pull everything together and run only a single test?

Thank you

Comment: heterogeneously normal data sub-sets If it is already established that data is so,  What for  normality or   ... test is tlo be requisitioned ?

Comment: please describe your problem.

Comment: the problem is: shall I apply parametric or not parametric test in the subsequent steps?

Comment: For what purpose ?

Comment: A p value of 0.07 (or 0.7 or 0.97) does not tell you that your data are drawn from a normal population.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/95357/gigiux please indicate sample of your data and variables.

Comment: @Gigiux what is your data . Indicate a part of it to let us know - count data or continuous data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to completely get rid of the Shapiro-Test for the following reasons:

1.- The 5% threshold is arbitrary. There is no objective reason to claim that the 1000 group is not normally distributed based on that p-value, other than that's what people are accustomed to do. If you remove one of the observations at random, you will get p-values above and below the 5% barrier, while the underlying distribution has not changed. The same applies to almost every group discussed here.

2.- No real-world data is normally distributed. The only reason why you cannot disprove it all the time is because your sample is not large enough. With more observations, the Shapiro-Test will always return a p-value as close to zero as you want, because small deviations from normality will become more and more relevant with large samples.

I would be consistent and use the same type of test in all four groups. At first glance, non-parametric testing looks like the option, but it depends on what your hypothesis is. For example, if you just want to compare means, you can go for a T-test

Comment: But if the data is not normally distributed, shouldn't I compare medians instead? And more in general, how should I decide what kind of test to use? If not the Shapiro-Wilks, how do I decide objectively when to use parametric or not parametric tests?

Comment: The kind of test to use depends on what you want to learn from the data. You can perform mean-based comparisons in non-normally distributed data. For the parametric/non parametric tests, you simply don't decide it at all. If you want to make a test for means or variances, use T-test or $\chi^2$-test respectively. If you want to make a "do these come from the same distribution"-test, use non-parametric tests instead

Comment: David Nowhere, it is mentioned that threshold is 5%. If you want to make a "do these come from the same distribution"-test, use non-parametric tests instead . - This statement needs a source to cite it. It  seems incorrect.

Comment: Well, if you actually read the question instead of jumping to criticize what others have posted, you would have found "Since only one of the groups is normally distributed (100)..." which sets the threshold between 4.561% and 7.890%. Applying Bayesian inference on the set of possible thresholds for p-values, I reached to the conclusion that 5% is the barrier used (with a, at least for me, high enough confidence)

Comment: To the best of my understanding, this Site is not meant for criticism without a reason. It was an ordinary comment.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar It was obvious that a 5% threshold was used, to the point that the OP accepted the answer without even mentioning it again

Comment: OP says something like and u apply Bayesian inference on 4 p values!

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar Nevermind

Comment: I always use 5% threshold since this is the most widely used level (unless I have to work on genetic stats, that is). In this case, I needed to compare the results of two tests.  I use the Shapiro-Wilk to determine if I should use parametric or not tests. The tests I used herein were the Spearman rho test for correlation (instead of  Pearson's r, and this choice is based on Shapiro's) of the results' measurement and Unweighted Cohen’s Kappa for the agreement of the two assays.

Comment: I would suggest against the use of the Shapiro-test. Jump straight into the non-parametric test! The fact that "everybody does X" does not imply "X is the rigth thing to do in every situation"